# Install clang 3.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 and see unmet dependencies errors

Tags: 12.04, clang

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install clang-3.3 clang-3.3-doc libclang-common-dev libclang-dev libclang1 libclang1-dbg libllvm-3.3-ocaml-dev libllvm3.3 libllvm3.3-dbg lldb-3.3 llvm-3.3 llvm-3.3-dev llvm-3.3-doc llvm-3.3-examples llvm-3.3-runtime
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clang-3.3 : Depends: libclang-common-dev (= 1:3.3~svn181304-1~exp1) but 1:3.4~svn182727-1~exp1 is to be installed
 libclang-common-dev : Depends: libllvm3.4 (= 1:3.4~svn182727-1~exp1) but 1:3.4~svn183792-1~exp1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Question> What should I do to solve this problem?

The repository I have used is as follows:

```
deb http://llvm.org/apt/precise/ llvm-toolchain-precise main
deb-src http://llvm.org/apt/precise/ llvm-toolchain-precise main
```

Answer (score 3):

You can read the list of packages provided by the repository at [llvm-toolchain-precise](http://llvm.org/apt/precise/dists/llvm-toolchain-precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages). You will see that it provides both 3.3 and 3.4 packages.

If you look at the error message, you will note that where the version number is not specified as part of the package name, the 3.4 versions are trying to be installed, which are not compatible with 3.3. `apt-get` always tries to install the highest version number.

You have several choices depending on why you need a particular version:

1) Use the default versions in the standard 12.04 repositories based on `clang 3.0`

2) Modify your command to use the 3.4 versions from the llvm repository.

3) Use `Synaptic` to specify the versions you need.

4) Force `apt-get` to use the 3.3 versions of the problematic packages. Warning: the man file `man apt-get` says this has the potential to destroy your system.

5) Build the 3.3 version and it's dependencies from source and install to Home.

Comment: How do you do 2) and get it from the llvm repository?